# Definition of partition of set regarding countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes

In Stochastic Processes, we define a partition of a set as:

> A countable collection of sets $U=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,...\}$(which may be a finite collection) which are pairwise disjoint is a partition of a set $D$ if
>
> $\bigcup A_i=D$

My question laying here is that, does the countability matter? Maybe both countable and uncountable collection are infinite, so there is no significant difference between them.

And many Stochastic Processes theories are fiddling with the concept of countability, I don't understand the meaning of that. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to define an uncountable sum it does not work out so well. So if you are summing over collections of sets it makes sense to restrict yourself to countable collections.